# Cannot uninstall Magento data migration tool (component type not set)

Tags: magento

First question here, so let me know if I am doing something wrong.

I have a Magento 2.1.4 installation and I am trying to uninstall magento/data-migration-tool by going into Setup --> Component Manager. Every attempt fails. Console log gives the following details.

---

```
[2017-04-26 01:05:02 CDT] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has been started

[2017-04-26 01:05:02 CDT] Magento maintenance mode is enabled.

[2017-04-26 01:05:02 CDT] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has successfully completed

[2017-04-26 06:24:02 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has started
Changed cache status:
config: 1 -> 0
layout: 1 -> 0
block_html: 1 -> 0
collections: 1 -> 0
reflection: 1 -> 0
db_ddl: 1 -> 0
eav: 1 -> 0
customer_notification: 1 -> 0
full_page: 1 -> 0
config_integration: 1 -> 0
config_integration_api: 1 -> 0
translate: 1 -> 0
config_webservice: 1 -> 0

[2017-04-26 06:24:02 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has been successfully completed

[2017-04-26 06:24:02 UTC] Job "setup:component:uninstall {"components":[{"name":"magento/data-migration-tool"}],"dataOption":false}" has started

[2017-04-26 06:24:02 UTC] An error occurred while executing job "setup:component:uninstall {"components":[{"name":"magento/data-migration-tool"}],"dataOption":false}": Component type not set

[2017-04-26 06:24:02 UTC] Job "setup:cache:enable ["config layout block_html collections reflection db_ddl eav customer_notification full_page config_integration config_integration_api translate config_webservice"]" has started
Changed cache status:
config: 0 -> 1
layout: 0 -> 1
block_html: 0 -> 1
collections: 0 -> 1
reflection: 0 -> 1
db_ddl: 0 -> 1
eav: 0 -> 1
customer_notification: 0 -> 1
full_page: 0 -> 1
config_integration: 0 -> 1
config_integration_api: 0 -> 1
translate: 0 -> 1
config_webservice: 0 -> 1
Cleaned cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
reflection
db_ddl
eav
customer_notification
full_page
config_integration
config_integration_api
translate
config_webservice

[2017-04-26 06:24:03 UTC] Job "setup:cache:enable ["config layout block_html collections reflection db_ddl eav customer_notification full_page config_integration config_integration_api translate config_webservice"]" has been successfully completed
```

Comment: i have same issue with magento 2.1.9 and datamigrationtool 2.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can uninstall a module through composer if it was installed using composer. If yes then use this command:**

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r <Vendor>_<Module>
```

-r flag removes module data. then issue:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**If module was not installed through composer:**

- remove the module directory app/code//
- drop module database tables (if it created any)
- remove entry from core_config_data and setup_module tables

Run command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```